# In Windows 11, how do I copy 13,000 files ONE at a time?

Tags: windows, copy, command-line-interface

First time asking a question here. Thanks for your patience!

I'm trying to copy 13,000 or so files from one folder on one local disk to another folder on another local disk, as a way to archive. The disks are sitting in a hard disk dock which is connected to my PC via USB. File sizes range from megabytes to gigabytes. OS is Windows 11.

Initially I thought it was no big deal and simply dragged all the files to the destination folder using Windows Explorer. But the copying process quickly hung (after successfully copying a couple hundred files), forcing me to restart my PC. I repeated this process several times, with similar results.

Along the way I noticed in Resource Monitor that about 20 to 30 files were being read and written simultaneously at any given time. This made me wonder whether the issue could be due to this "clever" multi-read and multi-write operation. So I decided to try command line, such as follows:

for %f in (*.*) do copy /b %f destinationFolder

This helped a lot but the copying still hung, typically after copying more than 2,000 files. Later I noticed that it was still doing the same multi-read and multi-write thingy. Now I think it makes sense because the "for loop" doesn't wait for copying of one file to finish before going to the next file.

I strongly believe that if I can somehow make the command copy one file at a time, i.e. do not start copying the next file until the current file is done copying, then the whole process will not hang.

Is there a simple way to achieve that? BTW, the source disk is Apple format and being accessed via MacDrive from within Windows 11. This might be the reason for the trouble in the first place. But I need to copy out the files. So I believe one file at a time should do the trick.

Help is much appreciated!